# Proof that degree of map is sum of its local degrees (prop 2.30 Hatcher)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Hatcher, in his proof of proposition 2.30 refers to the diagram
[image]

In his first line he simply says: By excision, the central term $H_{n}(S^{n},S^{n}-f^{-1}(y))$ is the direct sum of the groups $H_{n}(U_{i},U_{i}-x_{i})$ with $k_{i}$ the inclusion of the ith summand and $p_{i}$ the projection onto the $i$th summand.

> How does this follow from excision? This is unclear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By excision, $H_n(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))\approx H_n(\bigcup_i U_i,\bigcup_i U_i-f^{-1}(y))$, and since the open subsets are disjoint, each containing one point of the inverse image, the latter is $\bigoplus_i H_n(U_i,U_i-x_i)$.  This second step gives the inclusion maps $k_i$, which in other words each $k_i$ is the induced map for the inclusion map $(U_i,U_i-x_i)\to (S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))$.

The inclusion map $(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))\to (S^n,S^n-x_i)$ induces the map $p_i$, and the composition $(U_i,U_i-x_i)\to (S^n,S^n-x_i)$ induces an isomorphism by excision, so $p_i$ is the corresponding projection map.

---

Since my own answer confused me a couple years later, here is a more comprehensive diagram showing how it is that $H_n(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))$ is naturally a direct sum $\bigoplus_i H_n(S^n,S^n-x_j)$.

[image: Expanded commutative diagram for direct sum]

This entire diagram commutes.  Every map is marked with how it is obtained.  Most are induced by some map of pairs, some of which are marked with "$\approx$ excision" when the excision theorem applies.  The map between the direct sums is excision on each component individually.  The map $$\bigoplus_j H_n(U_j,U_j-x_j)\to H_n(\bigcup_j U_j,\bigcup_j (U_j-x_j))$$ is induced from all of the inclusion maps $(U_i,U_i-x_i)\to (\bigcup_j U_j,\bigcup_j (U_j-x_j))$ along with the universal property for direct sums, and it is an isomorphism due to the additivity axiom for homology.

The upper part of the diagram shows how going backwards from $H_n(S^n,S^n-x_i)$ through $H_n(U_i,U_i-x_i)$ to $H_n(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))$ via $k_i$ is the natural inclusion for $H_n(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))$ as a direct sum.  The lower part of the diagram shows how the induced map $p_i$ is the natural projection for the direct sum thought of as a direct product, using the fact that $H_n$ is functorial.  The identification of these maps as the natural inclusions and projections comes from the universal property of direct sums and direct products: $i$ should be thought to vary.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. Hatcher seems to like using excision a lot where it is unclear how.

Comment: In order to see that the $p_i$ are the projections, I think it needs to be added that $(U_j, U_j \setminus x_j) \to (S^n, S^n - x_i)$ induces the zero map on homology when $i \not = j$, so we also get that $p_i k_j =0$ for $j \not = i$. (Since in this case the map of pairs is contractible.) Do you agree?

Comment: The $p_i$'s are really coming from the projections $\bigoplus_j H_n(U_j,U_j-x_j)\to H_n(U_i,U_i-x_i)$ (defined using the universal property of direct sums, with the condition you describe, $p_ik_j=0$ for $j\neq i$), and then by naturality of excision you get the $p_i$'s in the diagram.  If you want to prove that the inclusion/projection maps for a finite direct sum of homology of spaces are induced by the inclusion/projection maps for the the disjoint union of spaces, then you might need to check your condition.

Comment: How did you show that $H_n(\cup U_i, \cup U_i- f^{-1}(y))$ is isomorphic to the direct product? Can you give a bit more detail on why this is true?

Comment: @Arbutus You can use the relative form of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.  Though, it's relatively straightforward to see that the chain complexes themselves split into a direct sum.

Comment: @KyleMiller What naturality property of excision are you referring to? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 I'm not sure exactly what I had in mind anymore, but I suspect I was confused and was only meaning the functoriality of $H_n$. (I've added a more comprehensive diagram.)

Answer (score 0):

the excision is applied to the triplet $S^n-\cup U_i \subset S^n-f^{-1}(y) \subset S^n$